# How to order the set of strings getting displayed in front end alphabetically in angular

Tags: angularjs, sorting

I have a set of strings displayed in front end.
The order of the string is displayed as 1,2,3,4,3A,3B,3C
But I want the order to be displayed as 1,2,3,3A,3B,3C,4
If an alphabet is found associated with the number, then that should be displayed first.
How can I achieve this in angular.

To display as 1,2,3,4,3A,3B,3C 
I am getting the values in a  array as shown below.

```
<span ng-repeat="x in numbers[0] | orderBy:x:reverse" ng-if="x.selected">
                 {{x.value}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
               </span>
               <span ng-repeat="x in alphabeticalnumbers[1] | orderBy:x:reverse" ng-if="x.selected">
                 {{x.value}}{{$last ? '' : ', '}}
               </span>
```

Comment: Can you just paste a copy of the set of strings that should be displayed? The actual set without any sort or order.

Comment: 1,2,3,3A,3B,3C,4 ( This is the set of strings that needs to be displayed) . The numbers should come first. Next , if any alphabets are found with numbers, it should come next in the series . Then comes the next set of numbers. As of now, I am unable to get this order. I am able to get only 1,2,3,4,3A,3B,3C  with the help of orderBy

Comment: If for example you have strings in this order: ['2','1','4','3','3A','3B','3C'] and the output should be 1,2,3,3A,3B,3C,4 then a simple orderBy would work.

Comment: In the js file, I am doing a concat of numbers[0] and alphabeticalnumbers[1] .

Comment: Can you provide a set of the input string to be sorted? What does your numbers[0] or numbers[1] or alphabeticalnumbers[1] contain?

Comment: Need the exact input for which the orderBy has to be applied to?

Comment: numbers[0] has 1,2,3,4,A,B,C
alphabeticalnumbers contain 3A,3B,3C

String to be sorted : 1,2,3,4,A,B,C,3A,3B,3C
Output : 1,2,3,3A,3B,3C,4,A,B,C

I am sorting both the arrays separately and doing a concat in js file and displaying the output string.

Comment: Well, don't do that. Concat them first, and sort the result.

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/mtp0kcdd/16/

In your html you could simply concat both the array's first and then apply a orderBy as below:

```
<span ng-repeat="x in numbers[0].concat(alphabeticalnumbers[1]) | orderBy:x">
    {{x}}
</span>
```

If your:

```
numbers[0] = ['1','2','3','4','A','B','C'];
```

and

```
alphabeticalnumbers[1] = ['3A','3B','3C'];
```

are the above array's.

Comment: The above method doesnt work. It still sorts as 1,2,3,4,A,B,C,3A,3B,3C
Ideally what I need is 1,2,3,3A,3B,3C,A,B,C

Comment: Looks like you had just cut short two lines of span to single line. It doesnt make any difference to the way it sorts.